Spark window operation with data skew
I am trying to make sense of some Spark metrics.
It appears that even though I have a relative good distribution of data, one of the tasks takes considerably longer to finish than the others, apparently because of shuffle read time.
Is this still because of skewness?
This appears while doing a window operation (note: column names were changed for privacy, but kept suggestive). This is processing 122B records with 240 executors (10 cores, 60GB, 14GB overhead - I know quite big, but found it to work better than smaller executors)
    df= = (df
    .withColumn(
        "duplicate_rank",
        f.rank().over(
            Window.partitionBy(
                "student_id",
                "student_address_id",
                "student_thesis_name",
            ).orderBy(
                "thesis_chronology_rank",
                "thesis_start_year",
                f.col("thesis_end_year").desc(),
            )
        ),
    ).filter(f.col("duplicate_rank") == 1))


Any suggestions for better approaching this are also appreciated.
I tried with a random salt (20 buckets) and performing 2 window operations (with salt and without salt) without a lot of success as the amount of time Spark spends shuffling data around is ridiculously high. I guess it also has to resort to a sort, as all of the keys are strings.
LE: I was doing some tests and it appears that repartitioning on a column from the dataframe "studen_thesis_name" improves performance by a bunch. Checking the physical plan I just see a window operation after the exchange? Does Spark still do a shuffle after, since it requires 2 more columns form the partition by? If so, why doesn't it appear in the physical plan?

Those metrics suggest that majority of time tasks spent not in actual processing but rather waiting to fetch shuffle blocks, see next to last line. There could be multiple reasons for that, including network and I/O congestion (as 10 tasks share 1 JVM in your configuration), large partition size (1.1GB is quite high), external shuffle service overload, etc., etc. Perhaps you can examine executor logs of the longest task to see if there are any clues. Otherwise, there is no evidence of a skew, data is distributed quite uniformly.

The only strange thing (apart from spills and some period of 20minutes without logs) is this warn: WARN TransportChannelHandler: 24/06/26 14:36:49 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /:
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_412]

20 minutes without logs doesn't sound okay. 74GB is a pretty large heap, but GC-ing even that size can't take 20 minutes. Anyway, I'd start by increasing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and slimming down executors to something healthy.

As you can see in the attached pic, GC time is ok. The reduction in executor size I observed reduces performance. I went with this approach to improve data locality during heavy shuffles (the queries executed do heavy shuffles) and it appears to be working, as slim executors (5 cores / 30gb for example) finish the jobs in longer times. Regarding shuffle partitions I've been keeping it around 3x total_cores ... I can always increase the no of executors but I am trying to keep that as last resort.

Did you increase the number of executors proportionally? I.e. 10 cores --> 240 executors, 5 cores --> 480 executors.

of course, 10 cores -> 240 executors 60GB, 14GB overhead / 5 cores-> 480, 30G, 7G. Here is an article on it for EMR (using EMR on EC2, but still same principles apply here) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-emr-serverless-supports-larger-worker-sizes-to-run-more-compute-and-memory-intensive-workloads/

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Right after going deeper on this, I was able to identify the problem as being Disk IO (EBS throttles). It could also be network, but that was not the case for me.

Great, thanks for sharing. Yep, hitting iops limits can be quite a PITA in IaaS setting.
